# Python Raspberry Pi GPIO and Wiegand issues

Tags: python-2.7, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, gpio

I'm extremely new to Python, I've been learning a bit over the last couple weeks. This is what I've managed to come up with. I'm pretty over the moon the code works most of the time.

I'm using 2 GPIO pins to read wiegand format from a reader to my Raspberry Pi 2. 
However, it doesn't always scan correctly. Occasionally scanning will hang on storing a bit and I'll have to fob the reader a second time to get it to finish. Sometimes it finishes correctly. Sometimes it finishes in a card number that is completely wrong. Usually fobbing a third time gets a new set of information that is correct. I've messed around with the c versions and python versions of PIGPIO to try understand what I'm doing differently. I can't figure out why it always seems to return a correct set of values from the reader using that code. I'm not knowledgeable enough to completely understand whats going on in the PIGPIO code so I'm unsure how to go about creating this consistency in my own code as I capture the information from the reader.

Does anything pop out immediately to anyone that indicates a fault in my logic for reading the information from the reader?

Remember, I'm super new so I need a little bit of hand holding with this.
I'm looking to capture only 26 bit card format off an HID 26bit card reader. I have 3 different HID format fobs/cards and I've been using them to test. The issue happens utilizing the same fob over and over and if I cycle through them using one after the other. Sometimes it will scan fine for 10+ times, other times it'll fail immediately and not work for 2 or 3 scans.

```
from time import sleep
import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import pifacecad as p
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
#GPIO setup
data0=38
data1=40
GPIO.setup(data0,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(data1,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
#Setting up display
cad = p.PiFaceCAD()
cad.lcd.backlight_on()
cad.lcd.clear()
cad.lcd.cursor_off()
cad.lcd.blink_off()
cad.lcd.write("Ready")
#Variables
i=0
dataBits=[]
bitCount=1
fcc="0"
card="0"
Zero="0"
One="1"
hexFilter=[]
hexCard=[]
hexFCC=[]
justRead=0
j=0
k=0
#Main code
while (1):
    #Reading code
    while (bitCount<27):   
        if GPIO.input(data0)==0:
            dataBits.append(Zero)
            print dataBits
            print "Bitcount %d" % bitCount
            bitCount = bitCount+1
            justRead=1
        if GPIO.input(data1)==0:
            dataBits.append(One)
            print dataBits
            print "Bitcount %d" % bitCount
            bitCount = bitCount+1
            justRead=1   
        if justRead ==1:
            if bitCount>26:
    #Transforming our information into usable bits  
    #Rest of the code just handles the information and prints to a screen. 
    #The issue existed before I wrote the rest of the code
```

I'm using a voltage divide circuit with resistors to drop the 5v to 3v and my data lines and Pi are all grounded together.

[Wiegand Hang](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8pYU.png)
[Wiegand Wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCyko.png)

EDIT:
Resolved here

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42118/wiegand-gpio-read-not-working-all-the-time-works-most-times-but-hangs-on-some-r

Comment: I don't see any code managing the timing/speed. How do you avoid reading a symbol (0 or 1) twice?

Comment: I hadn't considered it at the time. Nothing I'm actively doing in code is controlling that. I'm unsure how fast wiegand pulls the voltage down and back up. But the majority of the time I'm getting the correct values. I'll look into this and see if I am able to yield any useful information online.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I looked into this, a couple years ago (2018ish) it turned out python is not fast enough to read weigand directly and consistently.  That time I ended up putting an arduino on the RFID reader and having C code on the arduino read the weigand and put the values out as ASCII over USB/serial.

From what I've read, it should be feasible to read weigand from a raspberry pi using C.  I arrived at this page because I was looking to see if anyone had made a python/C library for reading weigand.  Haven't found it yet.

EDIT:  Hm, pigpio looks like it might do the job:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56706/raspberry-pi-as-wiegand-device-output-wiegand-to-receiver

http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#pdif2_tx_WD

Comment: I was able to get help from the creator of Pigpio. On the raspberrypi stackexchange. The answer is in there and I edited my question to display the changes that worked. I have a few devices made that have been reading 99-100% correct for years now. The error checking and time out code is really old and crude I'm not using it anymore so I don't recommend keeping it in. 
  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/42118/wiegand-gpio-read-not-working-all-the-time-works-most-times-but-hangs-on-some-r

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!  You might want to put this info in your entry above.